# Передача данных компоненту в React

Tags: reactjs

изучаю по немногу React, пытаюсь решать как задачи из примеров, так и придумываю их сам себе, захотелось получить список, в котором можно переходить от одной позиции к другой нажимая на кнопку. При этом, чтоб к выбранной позиции добавлялся класс 'active', как реализовать это на React?

- получается сделать список,
- менять на кнопке класс и надпись,

  Не получается:
- добавлять для позиции из списка новый клас после нажатия кнопки,
- реализовать переход по списку

Код:

```
  let games = {
      name: 'tanks',
      list: [
          'Panther',
          'Ferdinand',
          'Tigr',
          'T 34',
          'T 34-85'
      ]
  };


  class Li extends React.Component {
      render() {
          return (
              <li>{this.props.position}</li>
          );
      };
  }


  class Hello extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
              class: 'off', 
              label: 'Hello', 
              newClass: 'passive'
          };
      };

    click = () => {
        let colorBtn = (this.state.class === 'off') ? 'on' : 'off';
        let labelBtn = (this.state.label === 'Hello') ? 'Goodbye' : 'Hello';
        let classList = (this.state.newClass === 'passive') ? 'active' : 
 'passive';
        this.setState({
            class: colorBtn,
            label: labelBtn,
            className: classList
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className={this.state.class} onClick={this.click}> 
                    {this.state.label}
                </button>
                <ul>
                    {this.props.listgame.list.map(function (item, i ) {
                        return <Li  key={i} position={item}/>
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello listgame={games}/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Спасибо большое за помощь начинающим!

Comment: Как определяется "выбранная позиция"? Какому элементу надо сменить класс при нажатии кнопки?

Comment: Добрый день Дмитрий, хочу сделать следующий сценарий, чтоб после  нажатия кнопки добавлялся клас 'active' к 1 элементу из массива list, при следующем нажатии в класс 'active' переходил на вторую позицию по списку.. Пока не придумал как это реализовать

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно инкрементить позицию выделенного элемента и обнулять её если дошли до конца массива. А в компоненте элемента списка выбирать стиль в зависимости от свойства active (true|false).

```
class Li extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li 
                className={this.props.active ? 'active' : ''}
            >
                {this.props.position}
            </li>
        );
    };
}

class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            class: 'off', 
            label: 'Hello', 
            newClass: 'passive',
            activeGame: 0
        };
    };

    click = () => {
        let next = this.state;
        next.activeGame++;

        if(this.props.listgame.list.length <= next.activeGame) {
            next.activeGame = 0;
        }

        next.class = (this.state.class === 'off') ? 'on' : 'off';
        next.label = (this.state.label === 'Hello') ? 'Goodbye' : 'Hello';
        next.className = (this.state.newClass === 'passive') ? 'active' : 
 'passive';

        this.setState(next);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className={this.state.class} onClick={this.click}> 
                    {this.state.label}
                </button>
                <ul>
                    {this.props.listgame.list.map(function (item, i ) {
                        return <Li  
                            key={i} 
                            position={item}
                            active={this.state.activeGame === i}
                        />
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```